# How do I upgrade React from 0.13 to 15.0.1?

Tags: reactjs, version, upgrade

Please tell me step by step process of upgrading React from version .13 to 15.0.1 .

Answer (score 14):

Update react version in `package.json` 
Delete `node_modules` folder
Run `npm install`

install process will fail if there is any version mismatch among other dependencies in package file, console will show the expected compatible version number. Update those and run npm install again.

Once install is complete, then build your application and test. If any error appear due to deprecated code, then you would have to fix those as well.
One of the deprecated syntax from ver 13, is usage of react.render
There you will have to import react-dom and use that to call render. There can be many other potential issues which you may encounter. So test you app properly.

React entries in `package.json` that I have:

```
"react": "15.0.1",
"react-addons-perf": "15.0.1",
"react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.1",
"react-addons-update": "15.0.1",
"react-dom": "15.0.1"
```

All the best!
P.S. This is the process I follow, there may be some other way to do it.

Comment: Can you please send relevant links for these?

Comment: What things are deprecated and what errors might occur while upgrading?

Comment: The process for any version is pretty much the same as I mentioned above. Here is github [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html) for upgrade to ver 15, and npm [link](https://libraries.io/npm/react/15.3.2).
You have to change the version for react and add react-dom with your required version in package.json. These are two basic packages which you will need. Other dependencies depends on your application.
If you want to check the deprecated things, then you should go through the change log of each release and no one can you tell about the errors you will face.

Comment: If your existing code is clean and stable with no errors or warnings, then the upgrade process should be smooth. It should not take too much time. You can check the changelogs for [ver 14](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html) and [ver 15](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html), which will provide you info of the major changes done, which you may need to do in your code after upgrading.

Comment: Mihika - Please mark his answer as the correct answer. M.Sharma was very gracious to answer your question correctly, reward them with setting the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

By experience I can say that each version of react-native has breaking changes, for example from version 17 on, you need to remove @override on

```
 public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules()
```

So my advice is update progressively along with all you project dependencies.